# If, Else or Case statement in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to take the average of row only if the value is greater than zero. However, I am receiving the following error:

> *'Column 'Daily.Rad' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY...'*

Code:

```
SELECT Date,
       AVG([Speed]) as [Speed], 

       CASE WHEN [Rad] > 0.0
            THEN AVG([Rad])
            ELSE 0.0
       END AS [Rad], 

       AVG([Pressure]) as [Pressure], 

       FROM Daily 
WHERE MONTH(Date) = MONTH('08/31/2011')  
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: Where is the column `Daily.Data` in your SQL as indicated by the error message you specified? I could see `Daily.Date` instead. Is it a typo?

Comment: The error relates to the requirement that all non-aggregate columns (that is, columns not a part of aggregate functions like AVG, COUNT, etc), need to be in the group by clause.

Comment: That column `Daily.Rad` you need to specify with the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have given the correct answer if you want the average `Rad` across all rows, ignoring negative values. If, instead, you want the average for only positive `Rad` values, then you'll have to compute it yourself:

```
SELECT Date,
       AVG([Speed]) as [Speed], 

       SUM(CASE WHEN Rad>0.0 THEN Rad ELSE 0.0 END)
       /SUM(CASE WHEN Rad>0.0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Rad,

       AVG([Pressure]) as [Pressure], 

       FROM Daily 
WHERE MONTH(Date) = MONTH('08/31/2011')  
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: will this not cause problems if all values for a date are 0 or below ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - true. We can add some guards around the expression if that's a scenario the OP needs to deal with.

Comment: That should not be nessasary, check my answer for a better workaround.

Answer (score 1):

you need put the CASE clause in AVG function .

```
SELECT Date,
       AVG([Speed]) as [Speed], 
       AVG (
       CASE WHEN [Rad] > 0.0
            THEN [Rad]
            ELSE 0.0
       END) AS [Rad], 

       AVG([Pressure]) as [Pressure], 
        Date
       FROM Daily 
WHERE MONTH(Date) = MONTH('08/31/2011')  
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: Actually I want to take out the average only if the value is greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to exclude the negative Rad values from the average, then I think what you want is this:

```
SELECT Date,
AVG([Speed]) as [Speed], 

AVG(CASE WHEN [Rad] > 0.0
         THEN [Rad]
         ELSE 0.0
END) AS [Rad], 

AVG([Pressure]) as [Pressure] 

FROM Daily 
WHERE MONTH(Date) = MONTH('08/31/2011')  
GROUP BY Date
```

Answer (score 0):

This will eliminate the negative values and average the rest of the values. Also the where clause will cause better performance.

```
SELECT Date,
       AVG([Speed]) as [Speed], 

       coalesce(nullif( abs([Rad]), -[Rad]), 0) AS [Rad], 
       -- OR
       coalesce(AVG(CASE WHEN [Rad] > 0 THEN [Rad] END), 0) [Rad]

       AVG([Pressure]) as [Pressure], 

       FROM Daily 
WHERE Date >= dateadd(month, datediff(month,  0, '2011-08-31'), 0)
  AND Date <  dateadd(month, datediff(month, -1, '2011-08-31'), 0)
GROUP BY Date
```